# How do I find out the provisional profile for an IOS app in my itunes connect

Tags: ios

I am trying to upload a new version of my app, am I correct that the only way to do this is use the same profile as the original app?

If this is so how do I find the provisional profile used for the original app, I have my itunes connect but can't work it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your distribution provisioning profile will contain the same Bundle Id of the app which is in production. You can use that fact!

Comment: Thanks and if I do not have access to that Bundle Id, how do because the app was changed ownership to me, is it possible to update the app with a new version?

Comment: Hi @AdamKatz, This is indeed interesting. 
Well, technically, you can change the bundle ID to your own, you can create a brand new provisioning profile, sign the app using your private key and publish the app as a new one. However, I'm not sure how Apple will respond to that. If the ownership was changed, maybe you require written change of ownership so that you can show Apple as a proof.
Once your new app is ready, you may want to bring down the old one. I think this needs some discussion with Apple on what you plan to do!

Comment: Thanks for all your help, i should have actually made these two questions and you could have gotten 2 green ticks

Comment: Hope this helped you! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**If some one has changed the application ownership. the bundle ID associated with that application is transferred to new owner's account**

First of all find the bundle ID for your application.

You can find it  by going to https://itunesconnect.apple.com/ and then go to My apps

[image]

Once you have the bundle ID go to  **https://developer.apple.com/**
Then

***Account --> Certificates, IDs & Profiles --> Identifiers--> App Ids***

Here you will see the application bundle ID.

[image]

You have to use that bundle ID to create new profile.

[image]